# Battery meter shows 6 minutes left immediately after unplugging power, and hibernates sometimes

Tags: 12.04, power-management, battery

I have a Lenovo y400. Whenever I unplug the laptop, the battery meter shows `0:06` or less and the `Laptop battery critically low` message pops up. It hibernates once in a while, the rest of the time it increases gradually and shows the correct time after about a minute. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a power saving app like TLP. I've been using it since some days and it has been really efficient for my battery usage.

You can find a great configuration help for that here:
[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter)

Comment: My problem isn't battery usage. It's that the amount of charge/time left on battery is read wrong initially, hence the hibernating.